# c++: "unable to locate procedure entry point _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ in the dynamic link library"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string barra="-----------------------------------------------------------------------";
    string texto="";

    system("cls");
    cout << "Digite algo para aparecer entre barras: ";
    cin >> texto;
    cout << "\n" << barra << "\n";
    cout << texto;
    cout << barra << "\n";
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I have already tried to compile with g++ and gpp. I have also tried re-installing the compiler. It always returns the same error message:
"**unable to locate procedure entry point _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ in the dynamic link library**"
I'm new to c++ and I can't understand this error messages

Comment: What are the exact commands you are using to compile and what version is the compiler?

Comment: First I tried the vscode extension "C/C++ Compile Run", it didn't work so i tried via command line "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall 1.cpp". Same error, then i tried "g++ -std=c++14 1.cpp". The compiler i'm using is "mingw32-gcc-g++-bin 9.2.0-2"

Comment: Looks like your C:\Windows\system32 contains the obsolete libstdc++-6.dll. Read the duplicated topic in whole, it should help in solving the issue.

Comment: Thank you! should i delete this question?